# Displaying binomials and matrices using asciimath with mathjax

Tags: python-3.x, mathjax, asciimath

I'm trying to display different math problems using asciimath and mathjax. However some things does not seem to be supported in asciimath. For instance I'm trying to display a binomial/matrix and I can't really figure out how to do it. Would I have to use latex or mathml to do this, or is there a way to use asciimath for this?

update: I found a kinda cheeky way to show binomials in asciimath: (""_1^2) This works, but it is kinda hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
([1],[3])
```

to get a matrix with two rows of one element each surrounded by parentheses.  That may be what you want, though it may be too tall for use with in-line expressions.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! It is pretty big so I might have to find a way to reduce the size a bit. I might still go for the hacky version for binomials as the size on that works well for inline, but for displaying a matrix it seems pretty nice.